# How to push an item to array field of model in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 collections like this:

```js
const vocaSchema = {
    word: String,
    type: String,
    meaning: String,
    sente: String,
    semean: String,
    sug: String
};

const Voca = mongoose.model('Voca', vocaSchema);

const setVocaSchema = {
    lessonId: String,
    vocaList: [vocaSchema]
};

const SetVoca = mongoose.model('SetVoca', setVocaSchema);
```

and now I want to push a new `Voca` to `vocaList` field, and this is my code:

```js
app.post('/lesson/add-voca/:lessonID', (req, res) => {
    const lessonID = req.params.lessonID;

    const newVoca = new Voca({
        word: req.body.addWord,
        type: req.body.addType,
        meaning: req.body.addMeaning,
        sente: req.body.addStc,
        semean: req.body.addStcm,
        sug: req.body.addSggt
    });

    console.log(newVoca);

    SetVoca.findOneAndUpdate({ lessonId: lessonID }, { $push: { vocaList: newVoca } }, (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(result);
            res.redirect('/lesson/add-voca/' + lessonID);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            res.render('error');
        }
    });
});
```

and the result is `undefined` :(
[image] 

I don't know how to fix it. Anyone, please help me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push an object not a mongoose model.

Also you need to create a mongoose schema using `mongoose.schema`

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const vocaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  word: String,
  type: String,
  meaning: String,
  sente: String,
  semean: String,
  sug: String
});

//const Voca = mongoose.model("Voca", vocaSchema);

const setVocaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  lessonId: String,
  vocaList: [vocaSchema]
});

const SetVoca = mongoose.model("SetVoca", setVocaSchema);

module.exports = SetVoca;
```

And in your post route:

```js
app.post("/lesson/add-voca/:lessonID", (req, res) => {
  const lessonID = req.params.lessonID;

  const newVoca = {
    word: req.body.addWord,
    type: req.body.addType,
    meaning: req.body.addMeaning,
    sente: req.body.addStc,
    semean: req.body.addStcm,
    sug: req.body.addSggt
  };

  console.log(newVoca);

  SetVoca.findOneAndUpdate(
    { lessonId: lessonID },
    { $push: { vocaList: newVoca } },
    { new: true },
    (err, result) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(result);
        res.redirect("/lesson/add-voca/" + lessonID);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.render("error");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Test:

Let's say we have this document with an empty `vocaList` array:

```
{
    "_id": "5e61f34358a41b7ee0e6fa40",
    "lessonId": "lesson1",
    "vocaList": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

When we send a POST request with this url `../lesson/add-voca/lesson1`, and with this request body:

```
    "addWord": "word1",
    "addType": "type1",
    "addMeaning": "meaning",
    "addStc": "sente",
    "addStcm": "semean",
    "addSggt": "sug"
}
```

The result will be like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e61f34358a41b7ee0e6fa40"),
    "lessonId" : "lesson1",
    "vocaList" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e61f5900b73daa104e2ee75"),
            "word" : "word1",
            "type" : "type1",
            "meaning" : "meaning",
            "sente" : "sente",
            "semean" : "semean",
            "sug" : "sug"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: @ManhCuong I just updated answer, I made modifications to your schema also. Can you try like that?

Comment: I just edited my code like you, but the result is `null`

Comment: @ManhCuong can you check your collection if it is updated?

Comment: I checked that, it doesn't even create the setvoca collection, I make sure I cleaned the database before going to build with your code.:(

Comment: @ManhCuong ok I will try this

Comment: @ManhCuong I updated the answer, to see if the document is really updated, I just added `{new: true}` option,  also gave steps how to make it work.  Please not that first you need to create a SetVoca document.